# Troubleshoot EOF in POST request in go lang

Tags: go, http-post

I have method written in GoLang which is responsible to handle the POST requests and it reads the request body using the following way :

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

The code is working properly on Production, but in few cases i am getting `unexpected EOF`. I tried logging the request body using the [DumpRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest) method

But it is again giving me empty response. So, how do i troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Errors happen. Is it possible that clients just got disconnected or cancelled a request?

Comment: Thanks @JimB. Possibly it could be the reason i just wanted to understand the reason behind it.